# How to return Boolean properly in different NodeJS files?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

So I have files inside the following folder:

- app/controller/token.js
- app/controller/news.js

token.js:

```js
"use strict";

var connection = require("../con");

exports.isTokenExists = function(token) {

  var checkToken = "SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS 'total' FROM `user` WHERE `token` = '" + token + "'";
  var isExists = false;
  var count;
  var checkResult;

  connection.query(checkToken, function(error, rows) {
    if (!error) {
      checkResult = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
      for (var i = 0; i < checkResult.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        count = row.total;
      }
      if (count > 0) {
        isExists = true;
      }
    }
  });

  return isExists;

};
```

news.js:

```js
"use strict";

var response = require("../response/responses");
var connection = require("../con");
var getToken = require("./token");

exports.news = function(req, res) {
  response.send(false, "News API", null, res);
};

exports.allNews = function(req, res) {
  var checkTokenExists = getToken.isTokenExists("75d12cc4dc07608d5b87a6cba33cac056df1239c");
  if (checkTokenExists) {
    var allNewsQuery = "SELECT a.`id`, b.`title` AS `category`, a.`title`, a.`description`, a.`content`, a.`image`, a.`created_date` FROM `news` AS a LEFT JOIN `news_category` AS b ON a.`id_news_category` = b.`id` ORDER BY `created_date` DESC LIMIT 20";
    connection.query(allNewsQuery, function(error, rows) {
      if (error) {
        response.send(true, "" + error, null, res);
      } else {
        var data = [];
        var newsData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));

        for (var i = 0; i < newsData.length; i++) {

          var row = rows[i];

          data[i] = {
            id: row.id,
            idCategory: row.idCategory,
            category: row.category,
            title: row.title,
            description: row.description,
            image: row.image,
            createdDate: row.created_date
          };

        }
        response.send(false, "News is not empty", data, res);
      }
    });
  } else {
    response.send(true, "Error: Token not found", checkTokenExists, res);
  }
};
```

I always getting **false** value from isTokenExists meanwhile the token is exists in the table.

[image: Query same as var checkToken]

How do I get **true** response if the token is exist and how do I get **false** response if the token is not exists in table?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `connection.query` accepts a callback, but the rest of your code will move passed that without awaiting the result, which is why your `isExists` always returns false. You can fix this by encapsulating the query with a Promise like this:

```
"use strict";

const connection = require("../con");

exports.isTokenExists = async function(token) {
    const checkToken = "SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS 'total' FROM `user` WHERE `token` = ?";
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(checkToken, token, function (error, results) {
            if (error) return reject(error);
            return resolve(results.length > 0);
        });
    });
};
```

I also simplified the logic in the callback a bit.

Then, in news.js await the result like this:

```
exports.allNews = async function(req, res) {
    getToken.isTokenExists("75d12cc4dc07608d5b87a6cba33cac056df1239c")
        .then(result => {
            if (result === true) {
                //place your code for handling if the token exists here
            }
            else {
                //place your code for handling if the token does not exist
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            //handle error
        });
}
```

Comment: when I execute console.log(checkTokenExists) in news.js, I didn't get the true or false, I get this result instead: Promise { <pending> } in console. Any idea? thanks.

Comment: ah yes, i've updated my answer to show how you would use this in news.js as well :)

Comment: Even better, I've updated it again to use `?` in the query as is recommended

Answer (score 1):

You are missing async / await concept. You need to wait until your query executes.

1) Write a promise function

```
export.getCount = function(query) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let count = 0;
    connection.query(checkToken, function(error, rows) {
    if (!error) {
      checkResult = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
      for (var i = 0; i < checkResult.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        count = row.total;
      }
    }
   return res(count);
  })

}
```

2) Write async function which supports await operations

```
exports.isTokenExists = async function(token) {

 var query = "SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS 'total' FROM `user` WHERE `token` = '" + token + "'";
 let count = await getCount(query)
 return count > 0; // Returns true if count is > 0
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Michael's answer does a better job in my opinion. I'm thinking your answer is useful too. Cheers.